# Owl Carousel autoplay при наведении на слайдер

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

У меня есть несколько слайдеров, нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на каждый из них запускалась автопрокрутка и соответственно отключалась, когда курсор убран.

Вот вызов слайдера:

```js
$('.s-gallery').each(function() {

  var items = $(this).data('items');

  var options = {
    nav: false,
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 100,
    autoplayTimeout: 1,
    autoHieght: false,
    responsive: true,
    paginationWrap: $('.nav', this)
  };

  switch (items) {
    case 'single':
      $.extend(options, {
        singleItem: true
      });
      break;
    default:
      $.extend(options, {
        items: 3,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
        itemsTablet: [768, 3],
        itemsTabletSmall: [560, 2],
        itemsMobile: [479, 1]
      });
      break;
  }

  var owl = $('.enum', this).owlCarousel(options).data('owlCarousel');
  $('.prev', this).on('click', function() {
    owl.prev();
  });
  $('.next', this).on('click', function() {
    owl.next();
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="s-gallery">
  <div class="enum">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать в моем случае?
Пытался сделать так, но код не работает:

```
owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay'); 
$('.owl-carousel').on('mouseenter',function(){ 
   owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000]); 
})
$('.owl-carousel').on('mouseleave',function(){ 
    owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay'); 
});
```

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan, нашли решение?

Comment: @timur вопрос не я же задавал